# Parsing String to Date when sometimes year is missing and sometimes not

Tags: java, string, date

I am parsing multiple `String` objects containing date in format of **mm/dd/yyyy** into `Date` objects using `SimpleDateFormatter`

Problem I am facing is that, some String contain complete date means it is **mm/dd/yyyy** while some Strings do not contain year and comes in this format **mm/dd**

I am using this format to parse dates **MM/dd/yyyy** but everytime I get a String with only month and day, I get parsing exception.

I want to know, is there any way by which if a year field is missing then I can use something like **0000** or I need to tackle it into exception body only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know you can create an instance of SimpleDateFormat that does not "need" an year.
So just use an try-catch-Block

```
 try{
    //try formatting with simpledate instance with year
 }catch (Exception thrown when no year){
    try{
       //try formatting with simple date instace without year
    } catch (Exception e)
       //something went wrong both did not accept it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just create 2 separate `SimpleDateFormat` instances, one that you have and a second one with day and month only. You analyze the string first and pass it to the correct formatter.

Or pass it to the first one and if an exception is thrown, pass it to the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseDate(String yourDate);
{
try {
Date reqDate=sdf.parse(yourDate);//sdf is instance of you date formatter
return reqDate;
} catch (ParseException e) {
return null;
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

try Using this function. I think it will work. if thrown exception then null will return. In this way by checking null we know if it is correctly parsed or not.

Answer (score -1):

A code is worth thousand words....

```
        DateFormat df;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String s = new String("12/25/2012");

        String[] arr = s.split("/");

        if(arr.length>2){

c.set(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr[1]),Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
        }
        else{

            c.set(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
        }

        df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

        System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
```

You can later convert it **back to Date object** using the `df.parse(`) method...